# How can I browse Wikipedia's offline database on Linux?

Tags: software-recommendation, package-management

I've got Wikipedia's offline database in `.xml.bz2` format. There is also a software **WikiTaxi** to browse through it. But the problem is WikiTaxi is a Windows only software.

Is there any similar software that works on Ubuntu/Linux.

*Please don't suggest me about Wine.*

Answer (score 5):

> Kiwix is an offline reader for Web content. It's especially intended
>   to make Wikipedia available offline (see features). This is done by
>   reading the content of the project stored in a file format ZIM, a high
>   compressed open format with additional meta-data.
>
> Kiwix is a free software (GPL3), that means you can freely copy,
>   modify and spread it.<sup>1</sup>

Click here to [Download Kiwix.](http://www.kiwix.org/index.php/Main_Page)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Kiwix](http://www.kiwix.org/index.php/Main_Page)</sup>

Comment: Kiwix costs money to access the entire Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

Kiwix is the app for linux.
I want to add a tip for anyone who wants to use it and is running 64 bit system and cannot start the app.

You will know that you need to follow my instructions if the app does not start and you do not get any error messages.

After you download the package from [Here!](http://www.kiwix.org/index.php/Main_Page)

Open the folder , go to linux folder and then make the file " **Kiwix** " executable by changing it's permissions to be executed by yourself.

After that , when you try to start it , and nothing happens.

You must install the package **ia32-libs**.

The above package makes it possible to run **32** bit apps on **64** bit OS.

issue the following command :

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Hope that helps as I suffered really till I knew this piece of info and got the app to start and work.