# How and where can I get the Ububtu free Enzyclopedia?

Tags: launcher

I am teaching creative writing in a prison and would like to use the Ubuntu enzyclopadia as a research base for the inmates.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what software/package you are referring to (ubuntu encyclopedia??), but am aware wikipedia can be downloaded & used offline (debian, endless, ..) where I'm sure the same procedure would work in ubuntu.  I've only heard about it, and took no notice.  a quick scan found

[How can I browse Wikipedia's offline database on Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171860/how-can-i-browse-wikipedias-offline-database-on-linux)

which is very old, but may contain some clues.